# Removable discontinuity explanation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

If removable discontinuity can be removed and function can be made continuous..then what is the importance of studying removable discontinuity?

Comment: The motivation is perhaps to deal with functions defined via formulas which don't make sense at some points. For example $f(x) =1/x,g(x)=(\sin x) /x$ at $0$. The removable discontinuity helps to distinguish behavior of $g$ with that of $f$ near $0$ and we say that the issue with $g$ is not an issue. The problem of $f$ near $0$ is serious and it has consequences.

Comment: It is the same idea as a removable singularity. The function $f$ may not be defined as some point $x_0$, but perhaps we can find a new function $g$ which *is* defined at $x_0$ and also agrees with $f$ at all points except $x_0$. In this way, we can naturally 'extend' $f$ to be defined at $x_0$ through $g$. My favorite example would be $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ and $g(x) = 1$. This serves as an important segway into the world of analytic continuations, which is a topic of great interest.

Comment: "what is the importance of studying removable discontinuity?" so you learn about them, remove them, and make the function continuous